# How to use "trigger" in Excel 2010 to transcribe value into inputted row name and column name?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to use some sort of trigger to allow the user of this sheet to take an outputted value (through an algorithm I created) and transcribe it into another sheet.

The cell that it should transcribe the value to will be determined by taking the row name and column name from the user.

[image]

In this example, the user would insert X and Y as their row name and column name respectively. Once they click the trigger button (does not have to be a button, I am willing to use any type of trigger, but I assume there must be one in order for this to work), the value in the "Value (Rounded)" labeled cell will be transcribed to the corresponding cell:

[image]

This cell is where I want to insert the value.

The goal of this is automation. Ideally the user only needs to input the row name and column name and press a button (or any other trigger), which will transcribe the value into the other sheet.

Comment: Have a look at the [Worksheet.Change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel). The user wouldn't need to click anything to cause this to trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Does this have to be VBA? This can be done with a pretty simple formula.

Assumptions:

- The input sheet is named `Input` (change all references to Input to be the actual name of that sheet)
- The row name is in cell B1 (change Input!$B$1 to be the actual row name entry cell)
- The column name is in cell B2 (change Input!$B$2 to be the actual column name entry cell)
- The Value (Rounded) cell is in B4 (change Input!$B$4 to be the actual Value (Rounded) cell)

In cell B2 of our `Output` sheet, put in this formula and then copy over and down:

```
=IF(AND(Input!$B$1=$A2,Input!$B$2=B$1),Input!$B$4,"")
```

Comment: I noticed you put in "=$A2" right after "Input!$B$1=", where does A2 play a role and do I have to replace that with anything?

Comment: Column A contains your row names, so $A2 would be the first row name in your output sheet, which is why the formula goes in cell B2.  Same logic for row 1 containing your column names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event macro within the SHEET code (not module code). Here are two examples of how to get if a cell is changed or if a double click happens, both on specific cells:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3")) Is Nothing Then
    'Do something of Range("E3") has been double clicked
    '(Basic Example) 
    'Range("G3").Value = "Range("B3").value

    End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'If a cell has chanced...

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then
    'Do something
    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a button can be done by creating a shape (rectangle or any other), right click it and select "Assign Macro". There you can select a macro which should be carried out after clicking that shape. One note though, the macro needs to be a "public sub".